# Fixture globe too short for light bulb - want DIY suggestions

Tags: light-fixture, cfl, light-bulb

Any tips on how (read carefully) to extend the lip of a light globe so that the whole globe can extend further out from a light bulb base?

The proximate reason is that we want to use a CFL ("curly") light bulb in a particular fixture. As with many ceiling fixtures, the globe is secured to the base upside-down by screws that fit loosely under the lip of the globe.  The bulb is about 3/4" longer than the original, so the globe is now too short and can't be attached.

Yes, of course we could just use shorter LED bulbs! Or buy a new globe! But set that aside for now, because the technique potentially has broader applications.

Logically, the approaches are either lengthen the glass globe (that is, extend a secondary lip somehow) or add length using the attachment screw.  To create longer globe I've thought of a removable metal ring around the first lip, with a second ring serving as a new lip attached somehow.  A glue gun might be involved, or maybe soldering (I can't weld, and I'm not yet ready to learn glass blowing).

To add length at the attachment screw, I thought of a piece of metal approx 1 cm x 3 cm with a hole drilled in one end and the other end bent/curled up to fit into the metal lip.

Does anyone have other ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but that's a code violation (NEC 110.3 in *El NEC* nations), as it violates the instructions which came with the light and the conditions under which the light was listed by UL, CSA or relevant authority.

### Change the globe.

Most light globes have relatively standard bases.  A lighting supply shop will likely have other globes to fit that base.

If not, LED/CFL both have special cooling requirements that older fixtures are simply not designed to provide (since incandescents *prefer* living in an oven, it is literally their name).  This can greatly shorten the "bulb" life.  Most fixtures are cheap, and replacement fixtures are cheap, so you're better off getting a fixture that is well suited to the modern "bulbs" you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood? The bulb screws up into the electrical socket. Then as a cosmetic touch, to reduce glare, a glass globe is suspended over it.  Right now the thing's got a bulb in it and is shining away naked.  I don't see how the things I am asking about would affect the base, the wiring, or the cooling (or how this could be a code violation).